# Minimize the following function with integer values with the given constraint.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, integer-programming

$$f(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m)=(b_1)^2+(b_2)^2+\cdots+(b_m)^2$$
such that 
$$
b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_m=l$$

where 
$b_i$'s are nonnegative.  $m$ and $l$ are fixed positive integers. We want to minimize this function with integer values.

Comment: I just edited your text, but was unsure what you meant by n_1 = k.m + a. Is it $n_1 = k*m + a$ or $ n_1 =k$. $m+a$?

Comment: $k$, $m$ and $a$ are assumed to be known?any other relations, between $k$, $m$ and $a$?

Comment: It's not clear that "calculus" is an appropriate tag when the values are constrained to be integers.  Not that one should not use calculus for the problem if that were found to be useful for the problem, but is it a calculus problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me that the problem differs from minimizing $b_1^2+b_2^2+\cdots+b_m^2$ (I assume that the $b_3$ in the question is a typo for $b_m$) subject to $b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_m=N$. And it's clear you get the minimum by letting some of the $b_j$ be $[N/m]$ and, if $N/m$ isn't an integer, letting some of the $b_j$ be $1+[N/m]$. This follows from $2a^2<(a-r)^2+(a+r)^2$ and $a^2+(a+1)^2<(a-r)^2+(a+r+1)^2$.

But maybe the idea is that $m$ isn't fixed, and you're allowed to minimize over it, too. So, please edit the body of the question to clarify what it is that you want.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson
your solution is near to my result but I need more explanation so please explain it more
thank you

Comment: Sure. What precisely do you need explained?

Comment: may the newly edited version help you to explain it more.

Comment: Sure. What precisely do you need explained?

Comment: can I replace 2 by any real number >1. With the same argument?

Comment: You mean the 2 in the exponent? If $t>1$, can you prove $2a^t<(a-r)^t+(a+r)^t$? can you prove $a^t+(a+1)^t<(a-r)^t+(a+r+1)^t$?

Comment: I tried by binomial but I did not succeed, $2a^t<(a−r)^t+(a+r)^t$ gives minimum when $r=0$ I proved it by the first derivative test by taking $r$ is the variable.

Comment: Well, good! Then you have a proof, and everything's OK, right?

Comment: For $r\ge0$. $f(r)=(a-r)^t+(a+r)^t$ is an increasing function so it will give minimum for $r=0$. Similalrly, $f(r)=(a-r)^t+(a+r+1)^t$ is an increasing function again it will give minimum for $r=0$. Is it good, and enough for our result?

Comment: Pretty much. It shows that if the $b_i$ aren't all the same integer, or the same two consecutive integers, then the sum of squares can be decreased by increasing the smallest $b$ by one while decreasing the biggest $b$ by one. Right?

Comment: I think yes, need your confirmation.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Is there any way to contact you in future?